# Access denied for all users

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

In SharePoint foundation all user can not access the site even site owner also. I am getting Access denied error for all users. How can we resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are Site Collection Administrators also getting this?  What about farm Admins with access via Web Application Policy?

Comment: is it Kerberos or NTLM?

Comment: Dave , site collection administrator also getting same error. I don't about web application policy. Can say about it?

Comment: Couple of things to check, Make sure the Object cache configured properly? before this issue any change to farm i.e migration, Patch installation, Classic to claim conversion? Any error in the Uls Logs?

Comment: Burrhus, This is NTLM.

Comment: Waqas , Where can we see the UIs logs?

Comment: As Dave mentioned - try accessing the SP-CA with a Farm Admin account and for that particular Web Application check User Policies - maybe someone put Access to None for All Authenticated users, Everyone or Domain Users  - you know, the usual suspects when using "catch-all" groups